# Available Graph selection in LoadRunner Controller is empty

Tags: linux, performance-testing, loadrunner, health-monitoring, microfocus

I'm using LoadRunner Edition 12.63. I tried to extract monitoring from Linux server. I followed this tutorial: https://scottmoore.consulting/native-unix-monitoring-in-loadrunner/

Somehow, when I want to click on Available Graph in Controller, it is empty, tried to right click, nothing can do.

[image]

Appreciate if any experts can help how can I view the selection in Available Graph in LoadRunner Controller as shown in example below:
[image]

Is there any Micro Focus LoadRunner Adds In i need to download? Please advise! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Does your ID used for SSH access have access to the tools and data needed to build the graphs?

Comment: No, never used any for SSH access

Comment: Your ID has to be able to be used for SSH access and needs access to the utilities which produce the graph data.  See LoadRunner documentation for details.

Comment: Before this I use loadrunner for web load testing project, never use my ID and it's working fine. this time i revisit loadrunner after months, not able to view the available graph. Mind to share what topic to search for loadrunner documentation?

Comment: FYI this is not in the Analysis tool, this is in the LR Controller

Comment: Yes.  How do you think it connects to the LINUX host to get data.   Scott notes that we have been waiting for the agentless SSH based stuff from SiteScope to flow back into the controller.  For that, you need SSH based access and ability to run some command line tools.  See documentation.